# Eclipse batch search

Tags: eclipse, search

currently i have to ctrl+H every time insert a string and have to find it in *.java files.
I have about 600 strings to search.
I want to run a batch search where i provide a file with all strings (comma separated or in single lines) and eclipse run a search on it and preferably generate a file or console output to just show that which strings got matching and which not

Answer (score 0):

How about using `grep` from command line?

Comment: i have a complete java project in which i have to search strings.

Comment: i have a complete java project in which i have to search strings. grep will take many strings to search at a time but not a search in a folder and all sub files and folders. am i right ??

Comment: `grep -r` search recursively in a folder,
`man grep` for more details

Comment: i would realy appreciate if you provide an example. i want to search say 10 strings in a directory and i only want to search . java files

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse wont do it for you. You need to write a custom program. You can write java program. Make use of the Search API provided by eclipse. or simply use grep. If I remember correctly, the grep command would be

> find $dir_path -name *.java -exec grep -i $text '{}' ; -print